# inputタグにてplaceholderの文字サイズを小さくした時の、Chromeの挙動がおかしい

Tags: css

### 背景

`input`タグのplaceholder文字サイズを、通常の入力文字サイズより小さくしたかった。
そこで、以下のようなcssを適用した。

```
input {
  max-height: 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
input::placeholder {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

このスタイルでinputの見た目を確認したところ、Safari, Firefoxでのplaceholderは上下中央に配置されていたが、Chromeはplaceholderが上下中央よりも少し下に配置されていた。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 聞きたいこと

- Chromeのplaceholder文字位置を上下中央に戻す方法を知りたい。
  -- Safari, FireFoxも上下中央を維持した状態。

### 試したこと

###### `::-webkit-input-placeholder`で、Chromeだけ無理やり中央に移す

結果としては、Chromeは上下中央になったが、今度は逆にSafariのplaceholderが中央より上に配置されてしまった。

```
input {
  max-height: 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
input::placeholder {
  font-size: 16px;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder 
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome はプレースホルダを周辺のベースラインに沿って配置するようなので、おかしな動作とは言い難い感じです。

`vertical-align: middle` も効かないようなので、

- 気にしないで放置する
- Google Chrome のときだけ `position:relative; top:-4px` を適用するよう工夫する

でいいと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。となるとやはり、Chromeだけに適用するよう工夫する必要があるのですね。[ブラウザ別にCSSを適用する方法](https://netamame.com/browser-css-hack/)もあるようなので、こちらを参照しながらChromeだけにCSS適用しようと思います。